# How to set more then one editmode in one DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, windows

I have c# .net windowsapplication Project.

In that we have one module like broker Details.In this module using DataGridView to display the data.

The DataGridView Name is DatagridView1.

DataGridView1 have 5 columns like clientSurname,Initials ,productcode,transamt,total.

I set DataGridView1 editmode is EditProgrammatically.

I have do set Editmode Properties column wise

Eg:

```
**this.clientSurname.DataGridView.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystrokeOrF2;
this.Initials.DataGridView.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
 this.Initials.DataGridView.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystrokeOrF2;**
```

But this is not working...

Please help me how to fix the issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like described here for web forms.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289519(v=vs.71).aspx#vbtchtopquestionsaboutaspnetdatagridservercontroleditingmultiplerows

Something similar will work for Datagrid in Windows forms as well.

Hopefully this helps.